# Movement from first image immediately to the last image in a slideshow when clicked on the Backward button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 5 images which I wanted to display in a slideshow play. I have used the following code from internet and modified it slightly. The slideshow has two buttons, forward button on the right and backward button on the left. The forward button is functioning completely fine. When clicked on it, it correctly displays in the sequence: 
**Image_1 -> Image_2 -> Image_3 -> Image_4 -> Image_5 -> Image_1 -> Image_2 -> so on...**

But the problem is in the backward button, it displays correctly as :
**Image_5 -> Image_4 -> Image_3 -> Image_2 -> Image_1.**
But after this, clicking again on backward button, I want it to show as **Image_1 -> Image_5** without racing through Image_2 to Image_4. I am not able to do so. The function **sliderFaLeft.on('click', function(){}** in the file **javascript.js** is being created to do the same but unsuccessful.

```js
/*File : javascript.js*/


$(function()
{
    "use strict";

    var main_image_class = $('.main_image_class'),   
        slider          = main_image_class.find('.slider'),
        sliderUl        = slider.find('.slider-parent'),
        sliderUlLi      = sliderUl.find('.images-list'),
        sliderOl        = slider.find('.bottom-circles'),
        sliderOlLi      = sliderOl.find('.bottom-circles-list'),
        sliderFaRight   = slider.find('> .fa:first-of-type'),
        sliderFaLeft    = slider.find('> .fa:last-of-type'),
        sliderTime      = 1000,
        sliderWait      = 3000,
        sliderSetInt,
        resumeAndPause;

    function resetWH()
    {
        slider.width(slider.parent().width()).height(slider.parent().width() * 0.5);
        sliderUl.width(slider.width() * sliderUlLi.length).height(slider.height());
        sliderUlLi.width(slider.width()).height(slider.height());
    }

    resetWH();

    function runSlider()
    {
        if (sliderOlLi.hasClass('slider-active'))
        {
            sliderUl.animate(
            {
                marginLeft: -slider.width() * ($('.slider-active').data('slider') - 1)
            }, 
            sliderTime);
        }
        sliderFaLeft.fadeIn();
        sliderFaRight.fadeIn();
    }

    function runRight()
    {
        slider.each(function() 
        {
            $('.slider-active').next().addClass('slider-active').siblings().removeClass('slider-active');
            runSlider();
        });
    }

    function runLeft() 
    {
        slider.each(function() 
        {
            $('.slider-active').prev().addClass('slider-active').siblings().removeClass('slider-active');
            runSlider();
        });
    }

    sliderSetInt = function autoRunSlider()
    {
        if ($('.slider-active').next().is(':last-of-type')) 
        {
            sliderUl.animate(
            {
                marginLeft: -sliderUlLi.width() * $('.slider-active').data('slider')
            }, 
            sliderTime, 
            function() 
            {
                sliderUl.css('margin-left', 0);
                sliderOlLi.first().addClass('slider-active').siblings().removeClass('slider-active');
            });     
        } 
        else 
        {
            runRight();
        }
    };
    
    resumeAndPause = setInterval(sliderSetInt, sliderWait);    

    $(window).on('resize', function() 
    {
        resetWH();
    });
    

    slider.each(function()
    {
        sliderOlLi.click(function() 
        {
            $(this).addClass('slider-active').siblings().removeClass('slider-active');
            runSlider();
        });
    });
    
    sliderFaRight.on('click', function() 
    {
        if ($('.slider-active').next().is(':last-of-type')) 
        {
            sliderUl.animate(
            {
                marginLeft: -sliderUlLi.width() * $('.slider-active').data('slider')
            }, 
            sliderTime, 
            function() 
            {
                sliderUl.css('margin-left', 0);
                sliderOlLi.first().addClass('slider-active').siblings().removeClass('slider-active');
            });
        } 
        else 
        {
            runRight();
        }
    });

    sliderFaLeft.on('click', function() 
    {
        if ($('.slider-active').is(':first-of-type')) 
        {   
            /*Missing Code to move the animation from first image to last image through movement in the right direction*/
        } 
        else
        {
            runLeft();
        }
    });
    
    slider.find('.fa').hover(function() 
    {
        clearInterval(resumeAndPause);
    }, 
    function() 
    {
        resumeAndPause = setInterval(sliderSetInt, sliderWait);
    });
});
```

```css
/*File : styles.css*/

.main_image_class .slider ul, .main_image_class .slider ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.main_image_class {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
}

.slider .slider-parent {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.slider .slider-parent .images-list {
  background-size: cover;
}

.slider .slider-parent .images-list:first-of-type, .slider .slider-parent .images-list:last-of-type {
  background-image: url(facilities/classroom/image-1.jpeg);
}

.slider .slider-parent .images-list:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-image: url(facilities/classroom/image-2.jpeg);
}

.slider .slider-parent .images-list:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-image: url(facilities/classroom/image-3.jpeg);
}

.slider .slider-parent .images-list:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-image: url(facilities/classroom/image-4.jpeg);
}

.slider .slider-parent .images-list:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-image: url(facilities/classroom/image-5.jpg);
}

.slider .bottom-circles {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10px
}

.slider .bottom-circles .bottom-circles-list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.slider > .fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
}

.slider > .fa:first-of-type { right: 5px;}
.slider > .fa:last-of-type { left: 5px;}
.slider .fa {
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!--File : index.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="main_image_class">
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slider-parent">
                <li class="images-list" data-slider="1"></li>
                <li class="images-list" data-slider="2"></li>
                <li class="images-list" data-slider="3"></li>
                <li class="images-list" data-slider="4"></li>
                <li class="images-list" data-slider="5"></li>
                <li class="images-list" data-slider="6"></li>               
            </ul>

            <ol class="bottom-circles">
                <li class="bottom-circles-list slider-active" data-slider="1"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i></li>
                <li class="bottom-circles-list" data-slider="2"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i></li>
                <li class="bottom-circles-list" data-slider="3"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i></li>
                <li class="bottom-circles-list" data-slider="4"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i></li>
                <li class="bottom-circles-list" data-slider="5"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i></li>
                <li class="bottom-circles-list" data-slider="6"></li>
            </ol>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-5x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-5x"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way to achieve the goal is to get the length of the entire array of images, and, then use minus one. You can use for method:`for(i = images.length; i > 0; i--) { images[i] = image }` 
This method will fetch that index of images